# How to change the responsive variables of compass twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass

Here i am facing a problem with `compass_twitter_bootstrap_responsive` everything seem to be working fine but the `@media (min-width: 1200px)` is creating a problem. I want to change the variable of `$gridColumnWidth1200:  70px !default;` but its not working. However i have changed the variable of `$gridColumnWidth: 60px !default;` simply by placing it at the top of my scss file. But the same process is not working for responsive variables.

Any idea how to fix it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to the repliers.

Comment: are you sure the new value is being rendered in your outputted css?

Comment: yea its being rendered but while am trying for responsive's variables its not being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg .. After  a long time i tried again. Its same process just decleared the variable at the top. I just uninstalled the compass, sass and compass twitter bootstrap and again re-installed it. Its solved... :)